# UndefinedError: 'pyramid.util.Request object' has no attribute 'user'

Tags: python, authentication, pyramid, pylons

I am doing a simple authentication in python pyramid here is the security.py where am doing the authentication part.

**security.py**

```
from pyramid.authentication import AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy
from pyramid.authorization import ACLAuthorizationPolicy

from .models.user import User


class MyAuthenticationPolicy(AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy):
    def authenticated_userid(self, request):
        user = request.user
        if user is not None:
            return user.id

def get_user(request):
    user_id = request.unauthenticated_userid
    if user_id is not None:
        user = request.dbsession.query(User).get(user_id)
        return user

def includeme(config):
    settings = config.get_settings()
    authn_policy = MyAuthenticationPolicy(
        settings['auth.secret'],
        hashalg='sha512',
    )
    config.set_authentication_policy(authn_policy)
    config.set_authorization_policy(ACLAuthorizationPolicy())
    config.add_request_method(get_user, 'user', reify=True)
```

the setting are added to the init file that runs for the very first time and the request method is also added to request.

Here is my view file for the login where basically after checking the username and password and writing the remember code and store user info but may be this part is not working.

**default.py**

```
@view_config(route_name='auth', match_param='action=in', renderer='string',
                 request_method='POST')
@view_config(route_name='auth', match_param='action=out', renderer='string')
def sign_in_out(request):
   username=request.POST.get('username')
   if username:
     user=UserService.by_name(username)
     if user and user.verify_password(request.POST.get('password')):
        headers=remember(request,user.name)
        return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('admin'),headers=headers)
      else:
        headers=forget(request)
    return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('home'),headers=headers)
```

here after verifying username and password. I have checked that part is working am doing this copied from above 
**headers=remember(request,user.name)
return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('admin'),headers=headers)**

the admin route renders the admin.jinja2 so in the file
**admin.jinja2**

```
welcome {{request.user.name}}
```

doing this throws me an error 
**jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError**

> UndefinedError: 'pyramid.util.Request object' has no attribute 'user'

Comment: And how are you including the `security`?

Comment: config.include('.security') in __init__.py in root folder

Comment: 2 things come to mind: a) `get_user` throws AttributeError, or b) `includeme` is not actually run (perhaps you should debug print there)

Comment: Hey cool, you're using the new unreleased pyramid scaffold. It does seem as if the `includeme` function is not being called so you should double check that to be sure.

Comment: Yes am using the pyramid docs that is still in progress. So can you please help me the way to check that. How do we normally debug in pyramid am kind of very new to it . Thanks

Comment: instead of calling the get_user from the security.py I directly called it on the file itself  changing  __init__.py by writing down that get_user function on it and calling config.add_request_method(get_user, 'user', reify=True). Now am not getting the error but not showing any values either